# Android app KIOSK MODE turn on display when charging detected

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im developping app for tablets, its a car navigation.
What I need to do is - if the driver turns on car the tablet turns on screen, if the car is shut down display is off.
My first thought is to keep tablet plugged to the car charger and if the charging is detected turn on display. If the charging is not detected turn off display.
App would run in KIOSK mode. What would be the best approach to detect charging status while screen is off ?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.

First you need to listen for charging state changes. It can be done by:

```
//Create receiver
BroadcastReceiver powerChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        
        if(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED.equals(action)){
            turnScreenOn();
        } else if(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)){
            turnScreenOff();
        }

    }
};

//Register receiver
IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
registerReceiver(powerChangeReceiver, i);
```

and now all you need to do is to implement `turnScreenOn()` and `turnScreenOff()` methods:

```
public void turnScreenOn(){
    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "example:tag");
        wl.acquire();
    });
}

public void turnScreenOff(){
    if(policyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            policyManager.lockNow();
        });
    }
}
```

and don't forget to add `WAKE_LOCK` permission to your Manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Hope it helps!